# How to change title and meta tag dynamically like USA Today web page

Tags: jquery, meta-tags, pushstate, page-title

I want to ask about changing title and meta tags dynamically for SEO like USA today web page.

If you look at USA today web page, you will see that title and meta tags are changing dynamically and you can see that changes also in **page source** of the page.

I know history.pushState. I can change my url with that code. But it is not possible to change title with that code.

I know document.title and $('meta[name=author]').attr('content', 'New Author Name').
When I use these codes, I can not see the changes in **page source** of the page. I can only see the changes with chrome "inspect element" tool.

First question; what is the method that USA today web page use to change its title and meta tags dynamically?

Second question; is the method that USA today uses better than method I use or not in terms of SEO?

Thank you very much

Comment: Changes made to the document dynamically are never reflected in the source, the source is exactly what it sounds like, the actual source before you change it.

Comment: adeneo, did you check the USA today web page? You can see that page source changes.